# Load page and change margin using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to load a page using a link and depending on which link I click on, I want to change the margin on the page.
If I click on link 1, I want the margin to be 0, but if I click on link 2 I want it to be 350.

Is there a way to load a page and set the margin of an element if I know the ID in JavaScript? I'm quite happy to use JavaScript to open the page.
I don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: what you have done so far??

Comment: Can you give us a jsfiddle of what you have so we can understand the situation better?

Comment: I've got the page I want to link to with the ID or the element I want to change the margin of. I'm just not sure how to change the margin when someone navigates to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

www.myurl.com/page.html?1

Add link as below:
link 1
link 2

On Page.html write javascript as

```
<body onload="setmargin()">

<script>






function setmargin() {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    if(query==1)
    {//set margin as you want}
    else
    {//set margin as you want}

}


</script>
```

Comment: How do I do the link?

Comment: Works brilliantly. Thanks. I had to fiddle with it a bit.